# Local domain name resolution with WSL & Docker

Tags: domain-name-system, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm developing an app that is a combination of a Chrome extension and Rails backend (plus redis, solr and postgres). I've recently switched to developing on my nice home Windows rig instead of my macbook. The extension (running in a chrome browser on Windows) needs to be able to talk to the host (`https://company.localhost`) backed by the Rails server running in the WSL2 (`localhost:3000`).

The dependencies (redis, solr, postgres) are hosted as Docker containers and are reachable by the server (just regular ole `rails s`) without issue. I'm down to switch the server to be dockerized as well, if that helps out.

On Mac, there's a magic tool that handles all this (puma-dev), including the S part of HTTPS.

I'm not even sure where to begin with Windows & the WSL. Any pointers?

PS - I'm looking at puma-dev on the WSL, but there's indications that that might not pan out.

Update: Have `puma-dev` setup properly inside the WSL, so `ping company.localhost` resolves as expected.

Comment: Does your update solve the issue? I'm unclear on what your problem is. Can you show the problem by example and any errors?

Comment: The extension is getting a "connection refused" error. I think it's because the SSL part isn't working, or being bypassed through host resolution in Windows directly to 127.0.0.1 Still not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Open windows hosts file c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
2. Add a binding for your puma domain to localhost `127.0.0.1 mysite.test`
3. Save and restart windows